# JSON parsing android json arrays and json object

Tags: android, json

I'm getting a json response through volley, the response is as following :

```
{
   "status":"success",
   "message":"Request Successfull",
   "messagetitle":"Success",
   "show":"false",
   "goback":"false",
   "companies":[
      {
         "id":"14",
         "category":{
            "id":"1",
            "name":"test"
         },
         "subcategory":{
            "id":"1",
            "name":"test",
            "image":"https:\/\/page.com\/page\/uploads\/pagepics\/test\/testpics\/test.jpg"
         },
         "name2":"Company",
         "location":null,
         "logo":"https:\/\/page.com\/test\/testp\/testpics\/logo.png",
         "picture":"https:\/\/page.com\/test\/",
         "facebook":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/test",
         "instagram":"",
         "twitter":"",
         "telephone1":"+9611990454",
         "telephone2":"+961000000",
         "address":"Lebanon",
         "longitude":"0",
         "latitude":"0",
         "website":"www.website.com",
         "email":"",
         "desc":"asdasdas das das das dasda das das das dsadasdsadasdsad asd asd asd asd sad sa as das dsa asd das a a",
         "user":{
            "id":"21",
            "name":"X Y"
         },
         "status":"1"
      },
      {
         "id":"4",
         "category":{
            "id":"1",
            "name":"test"
         },
         "subcategory":{
            "id":"1",
            "name":"test",
            "image":"https:\/\/page.com\/test\/testp\/testpics\/test\/testphoto\/test.jpg"
         },
         "name2":"Your Company",
         "location":null,
         "logo":"",
         "picture":"https:\/\/page.com\/test\/",
         "facebook":"",
         "instagram":"",
         "twitter":"",
         "telephone1":"",
         "telephone2":"",
         "address":"",
         "longitude":"0",
         "latitude":"0",
         "website":"",
         "email":"",
         "desc":"",
         "user":{
            "id":"1",
            "name":"X Y"
         },
         "status":"1"
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to get all "image" and "name2" objects from the response. Here is my java code:

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                link, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //            Log.d("Request", response.toString());
                         try {

                              jarray1 = response.getJSONArray("subcategory");

for(int i=0;i<jarray1.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) jarray1.get(i);



     String url = object.getString("image");
     String name= object.getString("name2");
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),url+"\n"+name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }
```

Well it's giving me wrong info, any help please ?

Comment: Please let me know the error that you are getting, because facebook attribute is wrong I meant you need to add " in before the facebook

Comment: Awhen I run it in a for loop, it gives me the same info repeated, it's not entering the objects and extracting the strings. Any help ?

Comment: For the love of god and all that is holy, please format that code

Comment: your json array **subcategory** is inside another array named **companies** you need to get that json array first and by looking at your json response, I can tell that **subcategory** is a json object not json array

Comment: Ok so what are the adjustments that I need to implement in the code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly access inner objects in JSON, according to your json format you have to first get JSON Array of companies

```
JSONArray companiesArray = response.getJSONArray("companies");
```

Then get elements of the array

```
for(int i=0;i<companiesArray .length();i++){
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) companiesArray.get(i);
    // Now get subcategory information as JSONObject 
    JSONObject subcategoryObject =object .getJSONObject("subcategory");
    // Now you can get image and name from subcategoryObject 
    String url = subcategoryObject.getString("image");
    String name= subcategoryObject.getString("name2");
}
```

Comment: @MonzerYaghi first node??

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jAry=response.getJSONArray("companies");
for(int k=0;k<jAry.size();k++)
{
     String url = jAry.getJSONObject(k).getString("image");
     String name= jAry.getJSONObject(k).getString("name2");
}
```

you have to use like above code to get the output from the json. I have given it for example

Comment: *sry If there is any typo* why don't you check your answer for typo's before posting it?

Comment: @Tim Now I have edited my post and I meant the typo for my english

Comment: [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) and proper variables naming can go a long way when one needs to read your code. Make sure you name your variables in such a way that you can tell what they are and what they do without having to look at initialization. For example, *companiesJSONArray* would probably work better than *j_Ary*

Comment: @2Dee Ok I will follow

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SendPost() {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://your_php_url");

        try {

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postdata)); // Here postdata is BasicNameValuePair array with data to send
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

            GetResponce(result);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {

        } catch (IOException ex) {

        } catch (JSONException ex) {

        }

}

public void GetResponce(String responce) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(responce);

    JSONArray companies = myObject.getJSONArray("companies");

    String[] urls = new String[companies.length()]; 
    String[] names = new String[companies.length()]; //Here i'm initializing the arrays

    for (int i = 0; i < companies.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject object = companies.getJSONObject(i);

        JSONObject secondObject = object.getJSONObject("subcategory");

        urls[i] = secondObject.getString("image");

        names[i] = object.getString("name2");

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'll try it again and update my answer when im done :)

Comment: Are you sure you are sending your data rigth because it works for me.Also if you are doing something with String url and String name inside the loop it will show only the last records because it overrides these variables at every cycle. You can prevent this by sorting them in arrays for example - one for the names and one for the url's. I've edited my answer hope it helps now!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out :

```
                                try {
                                // response.getString("status");


                                    jarray = response.getJSONArray("companies");
                                  company_name=new String[jarray.length()];                     
            for(int i=0;i<jarray .length();i++){
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) jarray.get(i);
    // Now get subcategory information as JSONObject 
   // JSONObject subcategoryObject =object .getJSONObject("subcategory");
    // Now you can get image and name from subcategoryObject 
    company_name[i]= object.getString("name2");
}
```