# Error in parsing JSON - no value for jsonarray, PHP error?

Tags: php, android, json, android-asynctask

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    ListView list;
    TextView id;
    TextView name;
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.1.3/app/a.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_TRUE = "true";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "product";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    String pid,names,j;
    String s;
    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray product = null;
    JSONObject n = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();
    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity


    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pid);
            name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONArray json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            JSONObject jsonResponse;
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            jsonResponse = new JSONObject();
            try {
                product = jsonResponse.getJSONArray(TAG_TRUE);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             int c = jsonResponse.optInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
             if(c==1)
             {

                      j = jsonResponse.optString(TAG_PRODUCTS); 
                      for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){

  //                     productsList.(json.getString(i));    
                        pid = jsonResponse.optString(TAG_PID);
                        names = jsonResponse.optString(TAG_NAME);


                      }


                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_PID, pid);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, names);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                productsList.add(map);   
             }
                else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MainActivity.class);
      //               Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                   startActivity(i);
                }


            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    AllProductsActivity.this, productsList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {                 TAG_PID, TAG_NAME}, new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });


    // updating listview
     setListAdapter(adapter);

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array(); 
$r = array();
// get all products from products table
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=androidhive;charset=utf8', 'Sidd');

$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM product');
 $json= array();
 $json[0]= 'true';
//$r["a"] = array();

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
        // temp user array

        $response["product"] = array();
        $product = array();
        $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["product"], $product);
   //   array_push($r["a"], $response);
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $json[]= $response;

 }
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($json);

//}
?>
```

**Error message**

```
09-07 14:54:00.285: D/AbsListView(10521): Get MotionRecognitionManager
09-07 14:54:00.290: D/ProgressBar(10521): setProgress = 0
09-07 14:54:00.290: D/ProgressBar(10521): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
09-07 14:54:00.290: D/ProgressBar(10521): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
09-07 14:54:00.310: D/AbsListView(10521): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
09-07 14:54:00.310: D/AbsListView(10521): unregisterIRListener() is called 
09-07 14:54:00.310: D/AbsListView(10521): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
09-07 14:54:00.310: D/AbsListView(10521): unregisterIRListener() is called 
09-07 14:54:00.335: D/ProgressBar(10521): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
09-07 14:54:00.335: D/ProgressBar(10521): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
09-07 14:54:00.335: D/ProgressBar(10521): updateDrawableBounds: right = 96
09-07 14:54:00.335: D/ProgressBar(10521): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 96
09-07 14:54:00.395: D/AbsListView(10521): unregisterIRListener() is called 
09-07 14:54:00.445: D/AbsListView(10521): unregisterIRListener() is called 
09-07 14:54:00.520: D/All Products:(10521): ["true",{"product":[{"pid":"1","name":"sid"}],"success":1},{"product":[{"pid":"2","name":"shef"}],"success":1}]
09-07 14:54:00.520: W/System.err(10521): org.json.JSONException: No value for true
09-07 14:54:00.525: W/System.err(10521):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
09-07 14:54:00.525: W/System.err(10521):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:548)
09-07 14:54:00.525: W/System.err(10521):    at com.example.jsontry.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:104)
09-07 14:54:00.525: W/System.err(10521):    at com.example.jsontry.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
09-07 14:54:00.525: W/System.err(10521):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-07 14:54:00.525: W/System.err(10521):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-07 14:54:00.525: W/System.err(10521):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-07 14:54:00.525: W/System.err(10521):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-07 14:54:00.525: W/System.err(10521):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-07 14:54:00.525: W/System.err(10521):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-07 14:54:00.760: D/AbsListView(10521): unregisterIRListener() is called 
09-07 14:54:00.890: D/AbsListView(10521): onDetachedFromWindow
```

**

I am unable to parse data. What is wrong with my code?
I am new to Android and I am completely blank here. Any help would be much appreciated!
I have tried all kind of things here.
And what to do if I have to retrieve images from Database and show them in `ListView` or customview in Android?

Comment: Try running the php to see if you have the desired output, if it`s ok then look at your app

Comment: Please post your json

Comment: @Rajsundar : I can see that it is in the debug log: 
{"product":[{"pid":"1","name":"sid"}]},{"product":[{"pid":"1","name":"sid"},{"pid":"2","name":"shef"}]}

Comment: sry please check the Json format and your parsing is wrong

Comment: ["true",{"product":[{"pid":"1","name":"sid"}],"success":1},{"product":[{"pid":"2","name":"shef"}],"success":1}]

Comment: I accidently posted old logcat!

Comment: You have to format the json in php side, please check the link for Json object and jsonarray format I have give it for your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434443/json-parsing-android-json-arrays-and-json-object?noredirect=1#comment52733771_32434443

Comment: I don't know php part, please check with your webservice team

Answer (score 0):

remove repetitive keys like `product,success` from JSON, Format your JSON using PHP code and make it like below eg, which help you to parse JSON easily. 
eg :

```
{"product":[{"pid":"1","name":"sid"},{"pid":"2‌​","name":"shef"}],"success":"1","value":"true"}
```

if you will be able to create JSON like above. then you can parse it using below code

```
                   JSONArray productDetailsJsonArr = reader.getJSONArray("product");
                   for (int i = 0; i < productDetailsJsonArr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject pJsonObj = productDetailsJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                        String pid = pJsonObj.getString("pid");
                        String sid = pJsonObj.getString("sid");
                    }

                    String success = reader.getString("success");
                    String value = reader.getString("value");
```

Comment: the question is how?? :P

Comment: ["true",{"pid":"1","name":"sid"},{"pid":"2","name":"shef"}]

is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{

        $product = array();
        $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
        $response["product"] = $product;
        unset($product);
 }
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $json[]= $response;
```

Comment: ["true",{"product":{"pid":"2","name":"shef"},"success":1}]

returning this.
Not helping. :/

Comment: what is expected O/p?

Comment: ["true",{"product":[{"pid":"1","name":"sid"}],"success":1},{"product":[{"pid":"2‌​","name":"shef"}],"success":1}]

Comment: @Irfan, add code snippet for my above ans json.  Thanku

Comment: Basically i need pid and name only!

Comment: why do you want to get `success` with each product. you are getting product array extract it and get producut id and name.

Comment: im unable to exract it gives the error of No value for product

Comment: unable to understand your above code. Is it in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

There's problem with your `doInBackground` code

`JSONArray json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);`

here you are getting the data in `json` variable and nowhere you are using it